# Load more button not displaying anything

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am trying to display additional content, but my code is not working. I cannot seem to find anything wrong in the code, help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
<head>
<style>
  #more { display: none; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>Content</P>
<span id="more">
  <p>Content</p>
</span><span id="more">
<span id="more">
  <p>Content</p>
</span><span id="more">
<span id="more">
  <p>Content</p>
</span><span id="more">
...

<a href="#" id="load">Load More</a>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
    $("#more").slice(0, 2).show();
    $("#load").click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#more:hidden").slice(0, 2).show(); 
        if($("#more:hidden").length == 0){ 
            alert("No more"); 
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First thing first.. your `id` must be unique in whole HTML code

Comment: @Vaibhav could you please explain what you mean. I am quite a new to this.

Comment: use `$( document ).ready(function() {` instead of `$(function(){` to trigger the event.

Comment: I think this is what you are trying to achieve? https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_append

Comment: id must be unique: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H93.html

Comment: An `id` is unique in the sense that if you perform anything using an `id` as your selector, the code will always look for the first instance of that `id` and then stop looking. This is why `class` selectors exist.

Comment: please use code snippet for best explain your problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Hints for your approach:

You have different mistakes in your code:

1. You have more than one `id="more"`.
2. You try to use an opening `<span>` tag but you don't use the closing part `</span>`.

Here is a small working example similar to your code but it is not the best solution for your problem.

I changed html `id` to `class` to query more than one `<span>` element

```js
$(function(){
    var nextMore = 0;
    $("#load").click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".more").slice(nextMore, nextMore + 1 ).show();
        nextMore += 1;
        if($(".more").length - nextMore == 0){ 
            alert("No more"); 
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.more { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Content</p>
<span class="more">
  <p>Content</p>
</span>
<span class="more">
  <p>Content</p>
</span>
<span class="more">
  <p>Content</p>
</span>

<a href="#" id="load">Load More</a>
```

### (More) appropriate Approach:

As mentioned by other commentators, I guess you try to do something like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_append) to add/ append more html elements (e.g. buttons) to your html document:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    $("ol").append("<li>Content</li>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol>
  <li>Content</li>
</ol>

<button id="btn">Append Content items</button>
```